# Reset doesn't work for Ajax field (Yii)

Tags: php, ajax, yii, reset

I have a form, and one of the fields is populated via an Ajax call.
When I use:

```
<?php echo CHtml::resetButton('Reset');?>
```

it resets every field of the form except the one populated via the Ajax call...

How can I fix this?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should probably do something like:

```
$('#formid').clearForm();
```

Answer (score 0):

if that field is inside the form that rest button is, you can reset the form like:

```
 $('#myForm').trigger('reset').reset(); // this will clear validation comments too
```

Comment: Same as using <?php echo CHtml::resetButton('Reset');?>
I mean the result is not what I want...In this form I have 2 dropdownlists, second is dependent on the first. If I select a value from first dropdown then I select one from the second, and when I reset , everything else in the form is reset except the second dropdown in which the reset just selects the first element of that list...what I want is to totally reset that field, leave it blank, like it is when the page is loaded...

Comment: then you should have an option with empty value like `<option value=""></option>` as first option of your select, otherwise it's impossible to achieve what you're looking for without writing custom code